# Excel: Add labels to data points in XY chart

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I want to have labels next to data points in an Excel chart. There is a VBA code from Microsoft for this purpose:

http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/914813/en-us

```
Sub AttachLabelsToPoints()

   'Dimension variables.
   Dim Counter As Integer, ChartName As String, xVals As String

   ' Disable screen updating while the subroutine is run.
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'Store the formula for the first series in "xVals".
   xVals = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula

   'Extract the range for the data from xVals.
   xVals = Mid(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, ","), xVals, _
      Mid(Left(xVals, InStr(xVals, "!") - 1), 9)))
   xVals = Left(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, "!"), xVals, ",") - 1)
   Do While Left(xVals, 1) = ","
      xVals = Mid(xVals, 2)
   Loop

   'Attach a label to each data point in the chart.
   For Counter = 1 To Range(xVals).Cells.Count
     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).HasDataLabel = _
         True
      ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).DataLabel.Text = _
         Range(xVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value
   Next Counter

End Sub
```

It works so far. But only if the collection has no name:

[image]

When I name the collection then the macro returns an error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to use the code provided by Mircosoft and still be able to name the data collection?

Comment: did you do it right? I followed every instruction and its fine. when did this 'edit data row' popup box come? did you not copy the 3 columns before generate chart?

Comment: @ZAT: Thanks for the reply. I need to name the series (legend entry). I do it by right clicking in teh diagramm and selecting 'select data' (or something similar, I have the German version). Then you can give edit teh legend names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel 2013 introduced the capability to label a chart series with data from cells, after many years of users begging for it. Select the series, and add data labels. Select the data labels and format them. Under Label Options in the task pane, look for Label Contains, select the Value From Cells option, and select the range containing the label text.

[image]

And even before this, you could use a free add-in called the XY Chart Labeler (which works on all charts that support data labels, not just XY charts), which you can download from [Applications Professionals](http://appspro.com). It's written by Rob Bovey, a former Microsoft Excel MVP.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  All you need to do is replace the hardcoded '9' with 'InStr(xVals, ",")' and it will accept any length SERIES name in the field before the first comma.

Comment: it would be helpful to show the changed code chunk with an example of use.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I looked it up and InStr does: "The InStr function returns the position of the first occurrence of one string within another." So it look for the first occurance of the comma I guess. Without that change is looks for "9" characters?

Answer (score 2):

There already are some good answers like ZAT's one, explaining how to add labels to a data point in native Excel with VBA language.

But if you don't know anything about VBA it might be difficult to understand. For complex charts like this one I prefer to use Javascript which I think is more "readable" than VBA. And if you want to make a dynamic and interactive chart, javascript comes with a lot of powerful libraries.

Here is a working code I have written for you, with [plotly.js](https://plot.ly/javascript/) (the documentation is very good for js beginners) :

https://www.funfun.io/1/#/edit/5a60bbe7404f66229bda3e39

So to build this chart I put my data in the embedded spreadsheet, which I can then use in my javascript code thanks to a Json file.

I can create a scatter plot like so :

```
var trace1 = {
  x: firstX,
  y: firstY,
  text: firstLabel,
  mode: 'markers+text',
  textposition:'top right'
};
```

The `firstX` and `firstY` variable are the X and Y values.

To add a label to each point I added a label to `text` and changed the mode to `marker+text`instead of just `marker`.

Once you've made your chart you can load it in Excel by passing the URL in an Excel add-in called [Funfun](https://www.funfun.io/1/msaddin).

Here is how it looks like:

[image: final]

**Disclosure : I’m a developer of funfun**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not familiar with plotly.js yet but I have read about it in the past. Thank you very much for spending time on an old question like this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Problem with javascript is that the resulting chart is not an Excel chart, so for most it is static, uneditable, unformattable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this after chart generation (assuming chart in the same sheet):
(modify this according to your need)

```
Option Explicit
Sub RenameChartDataLabel()

Dim rngDLabel As Range
Dim iii as integer, pp as integer, dlcount as integer

Set rngDLabel = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A6")    'change range for datalabels text
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate  'change chart name
dlcount = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Count
iii = 1
pp = 1

For iii = dlcount To 1 Step -1
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(iii).Select
Selection.Text = rngDLabel(pp).Value
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
pp = pp + 1
Next
Set rngDLabel = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How do I name a chart? Is is the title?

Comment: use `ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "chart name"`

Comment: Could you reproduce my error? The benegfit ofthe MS code is that I do not need to speficy the Range manually.

Comment: I stated earlier that i had no error with MS code. I did not have to change anything there. Follow exactly same as MS code and maintain data arrangement in cell as described, you should have no problem.

Comment: And where you able to change the legend and apply the code afterwards? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: just edited with an image. what exactly are you trying to change: DataLabels or DataSeries?

Comment: Series name: I see that it works in your example. And you can still apply the original MS code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62181/discussion-between-zat-and-manuel-kuehner).

Comment: I cannot access teh chat on my work computer (it's blocked). I'll try it later in teh evening. But thanks so far. I see thre are too many comments by now.

Comment: I think you've got a small error: `For iii = dlcount To 1 Step -1` should be `For iii = 1 To dlcount Step 1`. Otherwise you are applying labels in reverse order (a mistake which is visible if you look at your own screenshot).